# html2pdf() javascript in laravel page-break for multiple pdf pages

Tags: javascript, laravel

hello to the whole community, I'm using html2pdf javascript in laravel to extrapolate graphs in pdf format, how can I set page breaks so that everything is arranged on multiple pages? I've tried everything but I can't get it to work. thanks so much in advance community.

This is code :

```
<script>
    $('#btn-one').click(function() {
        let div = document.querySelector(".tutto");
        html2pdf().from(div).save('dashboard-pers-layout-1.pdf');
    });
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using html2pdf.js library,

```
<script>
    $('#btn-one').click(function() {
        let div = document.querySelector(".tutto");
        html2pdf().set({
            pagebreak: { mode: 'avoid-all' }
        }).from(div).save('dashboard-pers-layout-1.pdf');
    });
</script>
```

reference: https://ekoopmans.github.io/html2pdf.js/#page-breaks

Comment: the only problem I have is a graph with overflow: auto, and it doesn't take everything in the pdf, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Define a CSS class that will be used to set the page break. In your HTML or stylesheet, define a class like this:

```
.page-break {
    page-break-before: always;
}
```

This CSS class uses the page-break-before property to force a page break before an element with this class.

Apply the .page-break class to the elements within your HTML that you want to have page breaks before them. For example:

```
<div class="tutto">
    <!-- Content for the first page -->
    <div class="page-break"></div>
    <!-- Content for the second page -->
    <div class="page-break"></div>
    <!-- Content for the third page -->
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

By inserting the  elements, you are indicating where the page breaks should occur when generating the PDF.

```
<script>
    $('#btn-one').click(function() {
        let div = document.querySelector(".tutto");
        html2pdf().from(div).save('dashboard-pers-layout-1.pdf');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: the only problem I have is a graph with overflow: auto, and it doesn't take everything in the pdf, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Include the **pagebreak** class in your HTML where you want the page breaks to occur. For example:

```html
<div class="tutto">
    <div class="pagebreak">
        <!-- Content for page 1 -->
    </div>
    <div class="pagebreak">
        <!-- Content for page 2 -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Modify your JavaScript to configure html2pdf to recognize the pagebreak class as a page break:

```js
$('#btn-one').click(function () {
    let div = document.querySelector(".tutto");
    html2pdf().from(div, {
        margin: 10, 
        pagebreak: { mode: 'css', before: '.pagebreak' }
    }).save('dashboard-pers-layout-1.pdf');
});
```

Finally make sure that your CSS includes styling for the page breaks.

```css
.pagebreak {
    page-break-before: always;
}
```

Comment: the only problem I have is a graph with overflow: auto, and it doesn't take everything in the pdf, how can I do it?